# How to find the shortest distance from line to parabola?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

How to find the shortest distance from line to parabola?

parabola: $$2x^2-4xy+2y^2-x-y=0$$and the line is: $$9x-7y+16=0$$
Already tried use this formula for distance:
$$\frac{|ax_{0}+by_{0}+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

Comment: You may rotate the whole picture so that the line becomes a horizontal or a vertical line.

Comment: If you translate the line parallel to itself until it touches the parabola it will become a tangent. So, find a point on the parabola at which the tangent has the same direction as the line. Then use that formula to compute the distance from that point to the line.

Comment: Since taking derivatives of implicit equations give you more directly the normal directions then you can compare those instead. For example, the line is perpendicular to (9,-7). and the parabola at the point (x,y) is perpendicular to (4x-4y-1, -4x+4y-1). But check yourself if I differentiated correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the graphs:

[image]

The tangent line to the parabola at the point $(x_0,y_0)$ is: $y=y_0+y'(x_0)(x-x_0).$

The tangent line must be parallel to the line, hence: $y'(x_0)=\frac97 \ \  \ (1)$

Take implicit differentiation from the equation of the parabola and solve the equation $(1)$ to find the point $(x_0,y_0).$

Then you find the distance between the point $(x_0,y_0)$ and the line.

Comment: Your equation for the tangent lines doesn’t include the case of a vertical tangent. That doesn’t matter for this problem, but it’s generally better to work with the gradient instead of the derivative to avoid having to deal with this special case.

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

The parametric equations are

for parabola
$$2 (x-y)^2=x+y $$
$$x-y=t $$
$$x+y=2t^2$$
thus

> $$x=t^2+t/2 \;,\;y=t^2-t/2$$

the   distance from a point of parabola to  the line is

$$D=\frac {|9 (t^2+t/2)-7 (t^2-t/2)+16|}{\sqrt{81+49}} $$

$$=\frac {2t^2+8t+16}{\sqrt {130}} $$

the minimum is attained for $t=-2$ and it is

> $$D_{min}=\frac{8}{\sqrt {130} }$$

Comment: After your hard work, we can safely minimize $$\dfrac{|9(2t^2+t)-7(2t^2-t)+32|}{2\sqrt{9^2+7^2}}=\dfrac{|4t^2+16t+32|}{2\sqrt{9^2+7^2}}$$  Now $4t^2+16t+32=(2t+4)^2+4^2\ge4^2$

Comment: @Salahamam_ Fatima Beautiful! +1. What do you think about mine?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg fine.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Use [rotation of axes](http://www.sosmath.com/CBB/viewtopic.php?t=17029) to eliminate the $xy$ term from the equation of the parabola as the distance is invariant in rotation.

Now use parametric equation $P(h+at^2,k+2at)$ of the parabola $$(y-k)^2=4a(x-h)$$ and $$\frac{|ax_{0}+by_{0}+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

We need to find the minimum of $$\frac{|9x-7y+16|}{\sqrt{9^2+7^2}},$$
where $x+y=2(x-y)^2$ or
$$\min\frac{|(9x-7y)(x+y)+32(x-y)^2|}{2\sqrt{130}(x-y)^2}$$ or
$$\min\frac{|41x^2-62xy+25y^2|}{2\sqrt{130}(x-y)^2}$$ or
$$\min\frac{41x^2-62xy+25y^2}{2\sqrt{130}(x-y)^2},$$

which is $\frac{8}{\sqrt{130}}$ because
$$\frac{41x^2-62xy+25y^2}{2\sqrt{130}(x-y)^2}\geq\frac{8}{\sqrt{130}}$$
it's just $$(5x-3y)^2\geq0$$ and the equality occurs.

Done!

Answer (score 0):

$$2x^2-4xy+2y^2-x-y=0$$

At a point $(x_0, y_0)$ on the parabola, the gradient is 
$\nabla f(x_0,y_0) = (4x_0-4y_0-1, -4x_0+4y_0-1)$

The direction of a normal to the line $9x-7y+16=0$ is $(7,9)$. So we must have

\begin{align}
   (4x_0-4y_0-1, -4x_0+4y_0-1) \circ (7,9) &= 0 \\
   -8 x_0 + 8 y_0 - 16 &= 0 \\
   y_0 = 2+x_0 \\
\hline
   2 x_0^2 - 4 x_0 (2+x_0) + 2 (2+x_0)^2 - x_0 - (2+x_0)  &= 0 \\
   6 - 2x_0 &= 0 \\
   (x_0, y_0) &= (3, 5)
\end{align}

The distance from the line $9x-7y+16=0$ to the point $(3,5)$ is

$$\frac{|9x_0-7y_0+16|}{\sqrt{9^2+7^2}}
 =\frac{|27-35+16|}{\sqrt{130}} =\frac{8}{\sqrt{130}}$$